# while training a network the iou_score is over 100

Tags: keras

I'm training a segmentation algoritm using a unet network on Keras
and I get iou scores over 100

> 107/200 [===============>..............] - ETA: 11:45 - loss:
> -1196.0438 - iou_score: 123.0177 108/200 [===============>..............] - ETA: 11:38 - loss: -1198.4695 -
> iou_score: 122.7428 109/200 [===============>..............] - ETA:
> 11:31 - loss: -1201.8632 - iou_score: 122.9272 110/200
> [===============>..............] - ETA: 11:24 - loss: -1204.7303 -
> iou_score: 123.1336

I thought that iou_score can only go up to 1. if it is perfectly segmented,
I'm I misunderstanding the measures, or do I have to so something else like normalizing the masks to range between 0 and 1 instead of 0 to 255?

Comment: please provide your `iou_score` function

Answer (score 1):

The  iou_score that is automatically generated only ranges from 0 to 1 if the target is normalized so values on the target image also range from 0 to 1 (instead of 0 to 255)